# React native - expo 45 - missing images android production

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I'm not able to see some images in android production build, the image are correctly displayed instead in expo dev-client, here my code:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={{ position: "absolute", right: 30, top: 20 }} onPress={() => this.setState({ displayInfo: !this.state.displayInfo })}>
  <Image source={require('./../../../../assets/icona_info.png')} resizeMode="contain" style={{ width: 36, height: 36 }} />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

It happen in expo sdk 45, with previous sdk all worked fine.
Please help  me to figure out how to solve this issue. Tnx

Comment: Seems that the problem affects all the image with 'source={require:path}', the network images (`source={{uri:url}}`) working as expected. It happen with eas build production

Comment: refer the following documentation https://docs.expo.dev/guides/preloading-and-caching-assets/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try caching the assets before you use them inside the components. You can use Asset and AppLoading modules to handle this. following is an example on how you can load assets before the components are loaded.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native';
import { Asset, AppLoading } from 'expo';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoaded: true,
    };
  }

  async loadAssetsAsync() {
    return Asset.loadAsync([require('./src/assets/icon.png')]);
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.isLoaded) {
      return (
        <AppLoading
          startAsync={() => this.loadAssetsAsync()}
          onFinish={() => this.setState({ isLoaded: true })}
          onError={console.warn}
        />
      );
    }
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{ position: 'absolute', right: 30, top: 20 }}
          onPress={() =>
            this.setState({ displayInfo: !this.state.displayInfo })
          }>
          <Image
            source={require('./src/assets/icon.png')}
            resizeMode="contain"
            style={{ width: 36, height: 36 }}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Please refer following documentation for more information.

[expo assets caching](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/preloading-and-caching-assets/)

[AppLoading](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/app-loading/?redirected)

[Asset](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v45.0.0/sdk/asset/)

Answer (score 0):

Try importing them like this

`import myImage from '../../path'`

and then

`<Image source={myImage} />`